# How can I connect my Galaxy 3 to my Mac?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-apollo, macos

How can I connect my Galaxy 3 (running Android 2.1) to my Mac?

Comment: What do you want to do with your Galaxy 3 once it's connected to your Mac? Do you just want to charge it? Or use it like a USB memory stick to load on/transfer files/music/pictures? Or do you want to sync in some way, either syncing a music collection, calendars, contacts etc? Or something else? These will all have very different answers, so would probably be easiest if you let us know what you want to do.

Comment: Want to sync it with mac... and also transfer the file... Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect Mac to have no trouble mounting the USB storage when you connect the device over USB, but if it does you coukd try PdaNet.  You can also transfer files over Bluetooth, WiFi, etc; please search for those solutions.  As for syncing, we jeed to know what exactly you're trying to sync.